# (EEVEE) Can't get Depth Of Field to focus on one object! (.Blend file included)

Tags: depth-of-field

i'm currently having a huge problem where i cant seem to make the camera focus on only one object, i want it to focus on the rabbit character:
https://i.gyazo.com/8a12c2843f8448bd6b2120e10753aa2e.gif
Yes i did "Focus on Object" as well, help would be highly appreciated.
And if you'd like to see the .Blend file for yourself since i may not be able to explain fully correctly, here's the blend file: 
https://www.mediafire.com/file/9m3q6w9vnhyqwgo/ribbii.zip/file

Comment: Welcome Crowny. Seems to work, so what exactly is your issue? Why do you can't just set the focus object to the character if that's what you want...?

Comment: Thank you! And i have no idea, i just want THAT one character to be focused at, but the depth of field just doesnt really focus on him. When i blur, the whole map gets blurry. I've tried "empty" focusing, i've tried "limit". Nothing really works, the only answer i might have is that maybe the map is too small if thats a thing? Since when i spawn a cube its almost half of the room. But resizing it also ruins my lighting. But i'll still try that too

Comment: Because your focus object (*Focus on Object*) is set to **Glitch1**, set it to the character as suggested. Otherwise please try to explain what else you wanna do, it seems to work fine.

Comment: I thought it was obvious? I want the camera to focus on the character without the character getting blurred while the background is blurred only. Kinda like this i've done with another poster: https://i.gyazo.com/7788622045f2f9893e27a9135aea0ae9.png
but in this poster the whole map gets blurred including the character. that's my problem. I dont want the character to get blurred as well and be focused on

Comment: It's *obvious* that your focus object is **Glitch1**. Is your character named like that? I think your expectations are wrong -> Depth of field is dependent on the distance to the object. If you want a finer gradient, move the camera closer to the object: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field